# Check if user has location access or not using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, geolocation

I have an angular app which is responsive and runs on different platforms e.g. Web, Mobiles including iOS, Android, Windows phones. I have a requirement to see if user has location access or not. What I have done is that used the following code to check if user can access location or not

That's how _isGPSEnabled is defined

```
private _isGPSEnabled: boolean;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(() => {
            this._isGPSEnabled = true;
        }, (error: GeolocationPositionError) => {
            this._isGPSEnabled = false;
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    console.error('User denied the request for Geolocation.');
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    console.error('Location information is unavailable.');
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    console.error('The request to get user location timed out.');
                    break;
                default:
                    console.error('An unknown error occurred.');
                    break;
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
```

I need to show/hide a button on _isGPSEnabled (boolean) value. This works fine on web but on mobile platforms, what is happening is that button doesn'tr show up and after navigating to another component and navigating back to this component, the button shows up. What I am thinking is that it doesn't get the value in time and button is not enabled. I started debugging but I can clearly see that this variable _isGPSEnabled always sets to true. I have used this in html file as below

```
<app-location-update
    *ngIf="_isGPSEnabled"
    (locationUpdate)="onUpdateLocation($event)">
</app-location-update>
```

In this app-location-update only one angular material is being displayed. I am not sure if it's the right approach to see if user can access current location using device or not. I just want to check if location/gps is enabled or not.

Here's location-update component

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

@Component({
selector: 'app-location-update',
templateUrl: './location-update.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./location-update.component.scss'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class LocationUpdateComponent {

```
@Output() locationUpdate: EventEmitter<IGeoLocationCoordinates> = new EventEmitter<IGeoLocationCoordinates>();

constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) {}

/**
 * Handle update location click
 * @param  {Event} event
 * @return void
 * @memberof LocationUpdateComponent
 */
updateLocation(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: GeolocationPosition) => {
            if (position) {
                const latitude: number = position.coords.latitude;
                const longitude: number = position.coords.longitude;
                const newLocation: IGeoLocationCoordinates = {
                    latitude: latitude,
                    longitude: longitude
                };

                    this.locationUpdate.emit(newLocation);
            }
        },
        (error: GeolocationPositionError) => console.error(error));
    } else {
        console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
}
```

Here's the html code for this component

```
<button
mat-icon-button
mat-raised-button
class="mcare-geolocation-button"
(appTap)="updateLocation($event)">
<mat-icon>add_location</mat-icon>
```

On clicking this button, user device's current location is obtained and emitted via event emitter.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show complete, reproducible example and not just code fragments. What is the initial value of _isGPSEnabled? What is onUpdateLocation?  What is app-location-update?

Comment: Updated as you asked.